# Should a support incident be opened for every stack dump, or just ones that cause an outage?

Tags: sql-server

Assuming that the stack dump in question can't be mapped to a know issue, if a stack dump doesn't seem to cause a problem and everything is working afterwards, should a support incident be opened for it?  Or should incidents be opened only when it causes an outage or loss of functionality?

Comment: This seems very opinion-based.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I can appreciate your opinion that this might seem opinion-based.  But it's not--which approach will result in me not wasting my time and Microsoft's support staff time, while still providing them the information they need to make the product better?  It would seem to me there is a definite answer, but perhaps only Microsoft folks know, or someone who's asked them this question.

Comment: If a stack dump is generated by SQL server, to me its a clear bug that needs to be investigated. Now if the stack dump caused a service interruption for your app and your business that part you have to handle it by proper monitoring and providing better visibility when your service degrades.

Comment: 3rd party modules, detouring, heap corruption, etc., can all have stack dumps generated by SQL server but SQL Server isn't the cause... so it's not quite 100% on that.

Comment: To be fair, if you read your question, it certainly could be interpreted that you mean "should I open a support incident?" as in "will I get any benefit from doing so?" If you are talking about more altruistic things, like making the product itself better, those should be stated in the question, but it still is something that only Microsoft would know for sure would help them. It probably depends a lot on things that your peers can't answer, like how serious is the issue, how prevalent is it, how easy is it to happen, is there an easy fix, does the team have time right now to investigate...

Comment: @TonyHinkle My2 cents, if I get a stack dump I would first check whether SQL Server is on latest SP/CU or not ?. Not all stack dumps are caused by bug in SQL Server some(very few) may also come when your SQL Server is under tremendous load. So before you open support ticket make sure who is the culprit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly cut and dry: If you want to actually work on the issue, collect data, uninstall/reinstall, isolate, test, potentially provide more dumps, potentially use things like appverifier and debugdiag or have a valid repro, then by all means open a ticket so it can be looked into and worked on.

If you just want to ship off a stack dump, with no other data, and have someone look at it in a vacuum, then I would not open a ticket as it'll have no traction and go nowhere. Neither party will be happy.

That's the short and sweet version.